# How do I convert RGBA raw buffer to PNG file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js I would like to compress a save a PNG image file from an array of raw RGBA pixel values.

```
  for (var x = 0; x < pixelSize; x++) 
    for (var y = 0; y < pixelSize; y++) {
      const offset = (y * pixelSize + x) * 4 // RGBA = 4 bytes
      buffer[offset    ] = x    // R
      buffer[offset + 1] = y    // G
      buffer[offset + 2] = 0    // B
      buffer[offset + 3] = 255  // Alpha
    }
```

How do I convert it to a PNG image file on disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) for example:

```
var Jimp = require('jimp')

const pixelSize = 256
var image = new Jimp(pixelSize, pixelSize, function (err, image) {
  let buffer = image.bitmap.data
  for (var x = 0; x < pixelSize; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < pixelSize; y++) {
      const offset = (y * pixelSize + x) * 4 // RGBA = 4 bytes
      buffer[offset    ] = x    // R
      buffer[offset + 1] = y    // G
      buffer[offset + 2] = 0    // B
      buffer[offset + 3] = 255  // Alpha
    }
  }
  image.write('image.png')
})
```

Comment: That was a very quick self answer

Comment: That's an odd mix of sync and async code. If creating an image from buffer is a fully synchronous operation, then why does it use a callback?

Comment: @riv The provided code does not work for me. It seems like the construtor calls the callback asynchronously. Writing the image this way yields an empty image for me. Calling image.write inside the callback works.

Comment: Thanks @riv.  Probably jimp changed behaviour. I have tested your suggestion which worked for me also.  The code in the answer is now updated with the fix.